# How to apply css style in GTK# with mono development

Tags: mono, gtk#

I am new to mono development with GTK# is that possible to apply css styles to an GTK button in mono development if so can you please explain how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No, The GTK# you get installed if you have a stable/release mono build is written on top of GTK2 which does not do the whole CSS thing. You'll need to wait for GTK# to move to GTK3, that said, the trunk of the [git repository of gtk-sharp](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp). Judging by [this commit message](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/commit/3ed7e0901e7f7d9849b0519ab7b1de2e9da2b33c) it now uses GTK3.